# jqgrid autocomplete on dynamic local source

Tags: jqgrid, autocomplete

Im trying to work form editing with autocomplete .. its source is different every time user opens edit form

when opening edit form :

```js
beforeShowForm: function(frm) { 
    var id = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
    if (id) {
        var ret = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',id);
        AccCode = ret.szAccCode;
    };
    $.post("url_getchildren", { szAccCode: AccCode}).
        done(function(data) {
                lschildcode=data;
        });
},
```

i have managed result from server,
but i cant send it to grid.

`colModel` :

```js
{name:'szAccParentCode',index:'szAccParentCode', editable:true, edittype:'text',
    editoptions : {
        dataInit: function(elem){
            $(elem).focus(function(){
                this.select();
            }),
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source:lschildcode
            })
        }
    }
},
```

why i cant pass `lschildcode` to autocomplete's source? and autocomplete kept sending term to server every time i type in the box.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `dataInit` (and so `autocomplete`) will be called *before* `done` of the `$.post` will be executed.

To fix the problem you can for example call `$("#szAccParentCode").autocomplete({source:lschildcode})` inside of `done`.

Another way: one can use URL as the value of `source`. The URL can contains some additional parameters. If you need use HTTP POST you can declare `source` as function and call `response` parameter (callback function) inside of `success` or `done` of your `source` implementation. Just look at the implementation of `source` in [the remote with caching](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache) example and examine the code (click on "view source") or examine the source code of jQuery UI Autocomplete near `$.ajax` usage (see [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/1.10.3/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L360-L362)).

Comment: thank you very much @Oleg ... i did it function(data) {
                                    $("#szAccParentCode").autocomplete({source:JSON.parse(data)});
                            } inside $.post

Comment: btw the source is not changing when i click next/prev record in edit form .. any suggestion where should i put this function?